# How to save login information on Cisco Packet Tracer 7.2 on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, cisco

Every time I start `packettracer`, I get prompted for my NetAcad login details. I want to avoid that and have my login information saved. How can it be done?

Comment: It appears that it's a bug, it's still not fixed in the current version (7.2.2 0418).

Comment: Can you provide sources where this bug has been reported, and said that it's still not solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no solution for this issue. The more recent updates for packet tracer too don't address it, even in windows.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found is to disconnect the internet from the computer every time before launching Packet tracer.

Comment: This used to work, but it was not "disconnecting from the internet", it was more specifically turning off your network interface. I had to work offline and I had no internet configured at all and I still had to deal with it. When I didnt have internet access I wrote a launch script for it to kill the interface so it could start. This question was years ago, I don't know if today's versions are still like this... and it doubt it was a "bug" or an "issue"...(ps Dear Cisco, I wasn't trying to get over... practicing at work was met with challenges :) ..plus you guys got a lot of money from me)